# How can you make a magik discord.py command python

Tags: discord.py

I've seen one about discord.js but my bot is made using discord.py so can someone help me?

Comment: Your question is not clear, Provide more details, you can put example.

Comment: What is a `magik` command?

Comment: for example, if I do c-magik my bot is gonna send a picture of a distorted version of my profile picture if I do c-magik @user it's gonna send that users profile picture but distorted

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [what's on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: "Implement this feature for me" is off-topic for this site. You have to make an honest attempt, and then ask a **specific question** about your algorithm or technique. If you have no idea where to start, you need to look up a tutorial or talk to a tutor.

Comment: You could use [dank memer's imgen api](https://dankmemer.services/documentation) for this, or manually do it with pil.

Comment: There is no tutorial about this Ceres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's Pillow library for Python which can be easily used for creating such effects using suitable filters and modes.

Pillow Docs: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/
Discord.py Docs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/

Answer (score 0):

You can use an API or make it yourself using a library